# scanf/cin is stucks in loop

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, stdin

I have a C++ program that performs a calculation on the given size of the array. it works fine on the small array but on the large array, scanf and cin get stuck and if I enter any non-digit, it breaks out of the loop which evaluates false calculations.

EDIT: If I separate the input on multiple lines then it works. So How can increase the line length limit of my OS ( which is Linux )

here is sample code which reproduces the issue:-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N;

    cin >> N;
    int *X = new int[N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cout << "getting " << i << "th input \n";
        cin >> X[i]; // tried scanf too but i
    }

    cout << "Done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

when I give large input like this one:- https://pastebin.com/PWmm9J7i

it print until

```
getting 693th input
```

I ran programm multiple time and still get same result. I also compiled it with clang and gcc but it still stucks at 693th input.

I am using Manjaro OS and ZSH shell

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/5eBvPw

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. There could be a funky character in the input, probably after the 693rd value.

Comment: the "693th" input comes at character position 4096 of the second line, so maybe your OS's standard input buffering or the method you're using to supply the input cannot exceed 4K line length, or something like that .  You could try adding some newlines to the input file so that no line reaches that length

Comment: @M.M you correct. separating input on multiple lines is working. Is there any way of increasing this line length limit on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that its is related to the [Canonical Mode Input Processing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_06).
more info can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal)

You can turn off canonical mode with `stty cbreak` or `stty -icanon`

I am using Zsh shell,So answers on the site I linked are not working for me. They do work for the bash shell. for now, I am using this technique to feed the input to the program:-

```
./program < input.txt
```

Comment: *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*). `./program < input04.txt` would be better.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks. Edited

Comment: Were you always using `./program < input.txt`, or are you saying that changing to that form fixed the problem? It would be good to update the question to show the method that was NOT working .

Answer (score 0):

First, the example you linked to runs fine. But you say: *cin gets stuck and if I enter any non-digit*. That's the expected behavior. To handle this, you need to check the state of `cin` and if it is in an error state, clear the error and consume the bad chars:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    cout << "getting " << i << "th input \n";
    if (!(cin >> X[i])) {
        // No more input?
        if (cin.eof()) break;
        // Clear error
        std::cin.clear(); 
        // Consume all input until next space
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
        // You probably also want to decrement i
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected error of cin

```
int i;
cin>>i;
if(cin.fail()) {
//error handling here
}
```